# dynamic csv to sqlite importing

Tags: python, sqlite, list, dynamic, csv

```
with open((path + 'stuff.csv'),'r+') as fin1:
    dr1 = csv.DictReader(fin1)
    create1="CREATE TABLE LGD ("
    exe1="INSERT INTO LGD ("
    for a in dr1.fieldnames:
        if a=='':
            pass
        elif ' ' in a:
            create1+=a.replace(" ","")+','
            exe1+=a.replace(" ","")+','
        else:
            create1 += a + ","
            exe1+= a + ","
    create1 = create1[:-1]
    exe1=exe1[:-1]
    create1 +=");"
        exe1+=") VALUES ("
    for a in range(len(dr1.fieldnames)-1):
        exe1+='?'+","
    exe1=exe1[:-1]
    exe1+=");"
    cur.execute(create1)
    to_db1 = [(a[dr1.fieldnames[0]],a[dr1.fieldnames[1]],a[dr1.fieldnames[2]],a[dr1.fieldnames[3]],a[dr1.fieldnames[4]]) for a in dr1]
    cur.executemany(exe1,to_db1)
    conn.commit()
```

ok my goal is to import each csv document as a table into sqlite database. Let's say I have 100 of them.

Right now my code writes the strings dynamically but how can i create the to_db1 list so I don't have to define how many columns there are?

specifically this line

```
to_db1 = [(a[dr1.fieldnames[0]],a[dr1.fieldnames[1]],a[dr1.fieldnames[2]],a[dr1.fieldnames[3]],a[dr1.fieldnames[4]]) for a in dr1]
```

I've seen this question, but mine is different because the fieldnames have spaces in them and they can't be takenout as many of the documents are uneditable. I also don't want to lose the list formatting shown below.

```
[(stuff,stuff,stuff),(stuff,stuff,stuff)]
```

[Dynamically import columns from csv into database table in sqlite3 and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854276/dynamically-import-columns-from-csv-into-database-table-in-sqlite3-and-python)

to restate my question, I want to create the to_db1 list without defining the column names at compile time. it should create it in this format

```
[(stuff,stuff,stuff),(stuff,stuff,stuff)]
```

at runtime.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. Before you create a table you have of course find out how many columns are needed (it is possible to add new columns dynamically but I think this wouldn't solve your problem)

Comment: the line I specifically pointed to goes through the csv and grabs the content for each row and adds them to the list. At runtime I want it to create the list without me defining the keys so specifically ex.a[dr.fieldnames[**0**]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the fieldnames without spaces and already joined by comma, you can use a list comprehension:

```
names = ['my _id', 'some a', 'some b']
sanitized_names = "({})".format(", ".join(x.replace(' ','') for x in names))

# => (my_id, somea, someb)
```

From there, you can reuse the answer you linked to.

To get tuples from the dicts in `dr1` ordered like `dr1.fieldnames`, use `[tuple(a[x] for x in dr1.fieldnames) for a in dr1]`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, look at the line I specifically point to. My code already takes the spaces out for the column headings of the table. However the keys cannot be changed and has to have the right spaces to grab the content of the csv.

Comment: I think I did. I've updated my answer, does that solve your problem?

Comment: yes it did, there was one extra column where the header and values are '' but that doesnt matter just named the column as useless in the table.  thank you